# Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type 'Null', flutter

Tags: flutter

```
kEditAccountPage: (context, state) {
      Map<String, dynamic> userData = state.data;
      EditAccountRoot(userData: userData);
    },
```

I wonder what I might be missing in the code, it shows the above screen error "Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type 'Null'"

Answer (score 0):

```
kEditAccountPage: (context, state) {
      Map<String, dynamic> userData = state.data;
      return EditAccountRoot(userData: userData);
    },
```

Simply add return before the widget.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your argument `kEditAccountPage` is expecting a `Widget`
but does not get anything.

So you need to return something back to it by using `return` statement.

```dart
kEditAccountPage: (context, state) {
      Map<String, dynamic> userData = state.data;
      return EditAccountRoot(userData: userData);
    },
```

or, go with the arrow function

```dart
kEditAccountPage: (context, state) => EditAccountRoot(userData: state.data),
```

My advice to you is to spend more time in studying software engineering and dart programming language before getting deeper in flutter